# upgrading from microsoft sharepoint yeoman 1.3.4 to 1.4.0 cause code to stop working

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have tried to upgrade a SPFx project from Yeoman 1.3.4 to 1.4.0 as a result of this React is upgraded from version 14 to version 15.6.

As a result my code has gone from working to not working :-

```
private _showAlert(): void { const alert: React.ReactElement = React.createElement( Alert, { message: strings.CustomSearchPlaceholderModeOnAlert } ); ReactDom.render(alert, this.domElement); }
```

Error :-
[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof Alert' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ComponentClass | StatelessComponent'.
Type 'typeof Alert' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent'.
Type 'typeof Alert' provides no match for the signature '(props: IAlertProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement'.
import Alert

This is what came out of gulp serve :-

Error - typescript - src\webparts\reactSearchBox\ReactSearchBoxWebPart.ts(129,6): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Alert' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ComponentClass | StatelessComponent'.

IAlertProps :+

```
export interface IAlertProps {
  /**
   * Message to be rendered in h1.
   */
  message: string;
}
```

Alert :-

```
import * as React from 'react'; import { IAlertProps } from './IAlertProps';

declare const window: any;

/**  * Simple react component that shows h1 element with text.  */ export default class Alert extends React.Component<IAlertProps, void> {   public render(): React.ReactElement<IAlertProps> {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.message}</h1>
    );   } }
```

Any Ideas anyone ?